# Lots of Continues in an Inner Loop and Dictionary of Actions

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) (Version 8) to update an existing PDF document and I believe its API is hurting me in this situation and was curious whether anyone had any comments on how this looks as it appears ugly to me.

The situation: I am replacing pages in PDF documents that are all generated by an in-house process so I can rely on their format being consistent and the following code is tasked with updating annotation links on the Table of Contents page(s) to point to the replace pages instead of the old pages. Since there can be multiple replacement operations, I decided to put the collection of these link annotations into a dictionary instead of looping through all of them for each replacement operation.

As my comments in the code mention, I only was able to piece this together by debugging a lot and examining the properties of different ABCPDF objects.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//use less than or equal to here because a one page TOC will have a matching start and end page number
private Dictionary<int, Action<int>> _linkUpdates;
WebSuperGoo.ABCPDF8.Doc pdfDoc;
for (var pageNumber = startPageNumber; pageNumber <= endPageNumber; pageNumber++)
{
    pdfDoc.PageNumber = pageNumber;
    var annotCount = pdfDoc.GetInfoInt(pdfDoc.Page, "Annot Count");

    //this is really ugly code that looks for link annotations (i.e. links in the TOC) that reference our old page Id
    //it depends on some nasty PDF data structures in ABCPDF and assumes they will always appear the same way
    //it took me a few hours of debugging to figure out how to get at this stuff and modify it, not pleasant
    for (var i = 1; i <= annotCount; i++)
    {
        //if at any level we come up empty, just get out of this annotation and try the next one
        var annotId = pdfDoc.GetInfoInt(pdfDoc.Page, string.Format("Annot {0}", i));
        var annotationMaster = (Annotation)pdfDoc.ObjectSoup[annotId];
        if (annotationMaster.SubType != "Link")
        {
            continue;
        }
        var annotItem = annotationMaster.Resolve(Atom.GetItem(annotationMaster.Atom, 0)) as DictAtom;
        if (annotItem == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var destination = annotItem["D"] as ArrayAtom;
        if (destination == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var destinationPage = destination[0] as RefAtom;
        if (destinationPage == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        _linkUpdates.Add(destinationPage.ID,
            updatedPageId =>
            {
                destinationPage.ID = updatedPageId;
                Atom.SetItem(destination, 0, destinationPage);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I included the declarations of `_linkUpdates` and `doc` for reference. So after I have this collection populated, when I have an update to make, I can simply do this:

```
if (_linkUpdates.ContainsKey(oldPageId))
{
     _linkUpdates[oldPageId](newPageId);
}
```

I fully understand that this logic is heavily dependent on an understanding of how ABCPDF works, but since there's a fairly active community on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abcpdf), I figured this might get some responses, perhaps from somebody who knows of an easier way of getting at/updating these link annotations.

So, to summarize the areas I am interested in feedback on are:

1. The prevalence of continues in my inner for loop
2. The choice of using a dictionary with an Action value to update the related ABCPDF object

This does work fine, and I am operating in an environment where I will have at most 70 possible link annotations to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you you create your own `IEnumerable` that wraps all this up very well behind an interface?

Then you can just do a `foreach` loop over the elements and not have to worry about the continues.

It would iterate over `(Annotation)pdfDoc.ObjectSoup[annotId]`'s

that is the way I would go about doing this.

```
public class Test : IEnumerable<RefAtom>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<RefAtom> _inner;

    public Test(pdfDocType annotations)
    {

        _inner = new inn(annotations);
    }

    IEnumerator<RefAtom> IEnumerable<RefAtom>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _inner;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _inner;
    }

    private class inn : IEnumerator<RefAtom>
    {
        private pdfDocType _annotations;
        private RefAtom _current;
        private int _max;
        private int _count;
        public inn(pdfDocType annotations)
        {
            _max = annotations.GetInfoInt(annotations.Page, "Annot Count");
            _annotations = annotations;
            _count = 0;
        }

        public void Dispose(){}

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_max > _count)
            {
                //do logic stuff
                //set current

            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _count = 0;
        }

        public RefAtom Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not quite following you here, could you post a small code sample to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the update, that does make sense and would at least hide away the ugliness behind the IEnumerable.

Comment: yeah I'm never a big fan of for statements, also you could even pass a func into the 'inn' class that does the calculation of determining if you can use it making this more usable for other applications

Comment: If you want to create a custom `IEnumerable`, there is a much easier way than this: use `yield return`.

Comment: @svick Can you elaborate on this some more I'm not sure I understand how yield will get you an IEnumerable.

Comment: @CSgoose I don't understand, the whole point of `yield return` is to create an `IEnumerable` easily.

Comment: @svick you're right I guess you just don't need to inner IEnumerator class, guess I learned something today.

Comment: I've given it some thought and I think this solution best meets what I am looking for. If I had enough reputation on code exchange, I'd actually vote for it too...

Answer (score 2):

If you do this often, you could write an extension method for `object` that takes a function, which is executed only when the input is not `null`. You could then use it in a fluent manner to navigate multiple times:

```
public static class Navigator
{
    public static TOutput Navigate<TInput, TOutput>(
        this TInput input, Func<TInput, TOutput> navigationFunction)
        where TOutput : class
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;

        return navigationFunction(input);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var destinationPage = 
    (annotationMaster.Resolve(Atom.GetItem(annotationMaster.Atom, 0)) as DictAtom)
        .Navigate(annotItem => annotItem["D"] as ArrayAtom)
        .Navigate(destination => destination[0] as RefAtom);

if (destinationPage == null)
    continue;
```

Notice that I also removed the braces. This is a matter of personal opinion (and sometimes company policy), but I think that they're not always necessary, especially when the body of the condition is this simple.

Comment: I like this idea, although for this one-off scenario, might be overkill.

Comment: Just put it somewhere in your assembly and declare it `internal` instead of `public`.  Or keep it public and find other uses for it.  I think I'm going to steal it for my codebase - there's all kinds of situations where it'd be useful...